# Becoming self-employed alongside a full time job, working abroad in the UK

Tags: united-kingdom, small-business, self-employment, working-abroad

I am a foreigner working full-time in the UK and studying part time at Uni. I want to study full time. In my old country, I used to draw and fix computers to earn some extra money.

What should I do if I want to become self-employed and keep my full time job? I don't want to sell any items or produce anything. I want to sell services only (Little things like painting a picture according to the clients idea, printing photos, fixing issues with computers). I predict my income to be about £50 per month or less on average.

I know about self-assessment form. But is it that simple? Is it the only thing I need to apply for? Do I need to pay any fees regularly like national insurance?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, check your visa conditions (if you're not from the EU): http://www.ukcisa.org.uk/Information--Advice/Working/How-many-hours-can-you-work

You do need to register for NI, but that's apparently streamlined into registering as self-employed: [How to pay N.I contributions when both employed and self-employed?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/28899/how-to-pay-n-i-contributions-when-both-employed-and-self-employed?rq=1)

(Realistically, you can almost certainly get away with doing <£50 month in cash-in-hand jobs with no paperwork whatsoever, but in the very unlikely event of being caught it could result in being deported)

Comment: I am from the EU. Also, I'd prefer to pay tax for even the low income, so I don't have to worry about it when I get new clients.

Comment: So I need to register for two things? Self-assessment and national insurance? Would doing only these two things make me a sole trader?