# Self-employment alongside full-time job

Tags: taxes, income-tax, united-kingdom, self-employment, self-assessment

I'm an EU national, currently resident in the UK and employed full time, paying tax through PAYE and NI. I already know that I could make additional £50 per month on average doing small jobs (IT help, printing images and painting pictures). I suppose they would all classify as services, not trading items. So I want  to become self-employed alongside working full time as an employee.

So far I've learned that my predicted income would be too low to pay any national insurance, so the only thing I need to do is to register for self-assessment. (Please correct me if I'm wrong)

Should I register for a business tax, too? Or is self-assessment alone enough?

And do I need to register as a sole trader?

Comment: Related: http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/71097/becoming-self-employed-alongside-a-full-time-job-working-abroad-in-the-uk

Comment: You may also have to tell your full-time employer or even get their permission (don't know much about employment law in the UK). E.g. in Germany, you typically have the right to get that permission  (with a few exceptions/conditions - e.g. you are not competing with your employer, you'll not work so much that your employer is liable to legal trouble because your total work time is illegaly high, etc.) but formally the employer has to grant it.

Answer (score 2):

What you need to do is [register as a sole trader](https://www.gov.uk/set-up-sole-trader).

This will automatically register you for self assessment so you don't have to do that separately.

For a simple business like you describe that's it.  Completing your self assessment will take care of all your income tax and national insurance obligations (although as mentioned in your previous question there shouldn't be any NI to pay if you're only making £600 or so a year).